# Complicated Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a code as below:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[property: string]: SimpleChange }) {
let change = changes["bgClass"];
let classList = this.element.nativeElement.classList;
```

I don't understand what this part means exactly:

```
changes: {[property: string]: SimpleChange }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have an object-array `[]` named **changes**, consisting of several Sub-Objects `{}` of type **SimpleChange**, that can be addressed by string `[<object-name>: type]`.

```
changes: {[property: string]: SimpleChange }
```

So you could have something like this (just an example)

```
let changeClass = changes["bgClass"]; // you get the object named bgClass
let changeState = changes["disabled"]; // you get the object named disabled
...
```

This way you can examine what exactly changed and fired the change event.

Comment: PS: If this helped you, please mark this answer as solution.